# interesting thread synchronization problem

Tags: multithreading, qt4, synchronization, pthreads

I am trying to come up with a synchronization model for the following scenario:

I have a GUI thread that is responsible for CPU intensive animation + blocking I/O. The GUI thread retrieves images from the network (puts them in a shared buffer) , these images are processed (CPU intensive operation..done by a worker thread) and then these images are animated ( again CPU intensive..done by the GUI thread).

The processing of images is done by a worker thread..it retrieves images from the shared buffer processes them and puts them in an output buffer.

There is only once CPU and the GUI thread should not get scheduled out while it is animating the images (the animation has to be really smooth). This means that the work thread should get the CPU only when the GUI thread is waiting for I/O operation to complete.

How do i go about achieving this? This looks like a classic producer consumer problem...but i am not quite sure how i can guarantee that the animation will be as smooth as possible ( i am open to using more threads).

I would like to use QThreads (Qt framework) for platform independence but i can consider pthreads for more control ( as currently we are only aiming for linux).

Any ideas?

EDIT:

i guess the problems boils down to one thing..how do i ensure that the animation thread is not interrupted  while it is animating the images ( the animation runs when the user goes from one page to the other..all the images in the new page are animated before shown in their proper place..this is a small operation but it must be really smooth).The worker thread can only run when the animation is over..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thinking out loud here, but it sounds like you have two compute-intensive tasks, `animation` and `processing`, and you want `animation` to always have priority over `processing`.  If that is correct then maybe instead of having these tasks in separate threads you could have a single thread that handles both `animation` and `processing`.

For instance, the thread could have two task-queues, one for `animation` jobs and one for `processing` jobs, and it only starts a job from the `processing` queue when the `animation` queue is empty.  But, this will only work well if each individual `processing` job is relatively small and/or interruptible at arbitrary positions (otherwise `animation` jobs will get delayed, which is not what you want).

Comment: true...the animation jobs should have higher priority...how do i guarantee this...the processing job is not small..so i cannot have a single thread.

Comment: another issue is I/O...in a single thread implementation i cannot take advantage of I/O delays to process images i already have...

Comment: Well, guaranteeing that the processing job does not start when an animation job is running is fairly simple.  A standard lock/semaphore pattern will do for that.  Terminating/pausing an in-flight processing job when an animation job starts is a lot trickier.  At a high level you'd need a way to pass a message to the processing thread that says "animation is starting", and then internally the processing thread need to do what it can to minimize (or stop) its resource consumption until the animation stops.  I'm not sure an out-of-the-box solution exists for this.

Answer (score 1):

The first big question is: Do I really need threads? Qt 's event system and network objects make it easy to **not having the technical burden** of threads and all the snags that comes with it.

Have a look at alternative ways to address issues [here](http://blog.exys.org/entries/2010/thread_abuse.html) and [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects). These techniques great if you are sticking to pure Qt code and do not depend on a 3rd party library. If you must use a 3rd party lib that does blocking calls then sure, you can use threads.

[Here](http://cartan.cas.suffolk.edu/oopdocbook/html/giant.html) is an example of a consumer producer.

Also have a look at [Advanced Qt Programming: Creating Great Software with C++ and Qt 4](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321635906)

My advice is to start without threads and see how it fares. You can always refactor to threads after. So, best is to design your objects/architecture without too much coupling.

If you want you can post some code to give more context.

Comment: The QT articles mentioned are excellent and after reading them i will be in a better position to judge..thanks!..the book is new though..will check that as well!

Comment: Just tip: If you can do network with Qt you could probably avoid threads if you do not want to scale on CPUs. If not, threads are the only answers and there are lots of examples on the web and even in the qt examples. We would need a bit more info on your project to give specific advise.

Comment: only one CPU is involved so scaling is not the objective....this is what inspired the whole thing...http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/01/21/qt-graphics-and-performance-generating-content-in-threads/ ....my use case is the same.

Comment: Another example without threads is in "C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4, Second Edition" > Chapter 7. Event Processing > Staying Responsive during Intensive Processing. And then a good treading one on Chapter 14. Multithreading > Communicating with the Main Thread.